# In s3 copy_object operation Is metadata_directive affect on tagging directve and how?

Tags: amazon-s3

If we set only metadata directive in copy object operation then what happens with tagging?

Answer (score 0):

Object tags are copied by default.

See [PUT Object Copy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectCOPY.html) in the S3 API Reference.  This is the refefence documentation to the APIs used by the various SDKs.

There's a separate directive, `x-amz-tagging-directive`, that controls this behavior, which is similar in implementation to the one used for metadata.  The SDKs each have their own ways that you access this, but the underlying behavior is the same.

Comment: Ok. I will check it. Thanks.